# Appending Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, append, std, cin

Exercise P6.07 from C++ For Everyone: Write a function `vector<int> append(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)` that appends `b` after `a`

Ex. `a is 1 4 9 16` and `b is 9 7 4 9 11` then it returns `1 4 9 16 9 7 4 9 11`

My Function

```
vector<int> append(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
    vector<int> appended;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        appended.push_back(a[i]);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
    {
        appended.push_back(b[i]);
    }

    return appended;
}
```

One of my tries:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter some numbers: ";
    int input, input2;
    vector<int> a, b;
    while (cin >> input)
    {
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Enter some numbers: ";
            while (cin >> input2)
            {
                if (cin.fail()) {break;}
                else {b.push_back(input2);}
            }
        }
        else {a.push_back(input);}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How would I use `cin` to get the vectors `a` and `b` when I run the `main()` function?

Comment: I don't understand the nested loop. And `while(cin >> input)` already breaks the loop when the extraction fails: the check for `.fail()` is needless (and in the case of the outer loop, _never invoked_.)

Comment: Right now, it just terminates

Comment: Why did you edit out the relevant part of the code, and leave the append function which is really not relevant to the question?

Comment: Actually, that was just one of my guess-tries that didn't work. I just need to know how you can put values into 2 vectors using `cin` and the book only showed an example with only 1 vector not 2. I'll put it back up

Comment: How would I use `cin` to get the vectors `a` and `b` when I run the `main()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask two questions: How do I append two vectors, and how do I input two sets of numbers.

As for the first, I would use `std::vector::insert` as others have described. As for the second, I have two alternatives.

You could use a sentinel value (-1, say, if all of you other numbers are positive) to indicate the end of the first list. If that is not an option, you could read the first set of numbers on a single line instead of from multiple lines.

Here are two programs that do what you are trying to do.

First, a program that uses -1 as a sentinel value:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

#include <iterator>
using std::ostream_iterator;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;


int main()
{
    int i;
    vector<int> v1;
    while(cin >> i) {
        if(i == -1)
            break;
        v1.push_back(i);
    }
    vector<int> v2;
    while(cin >> i)
        v2.push_back(i);

    v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());

    copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
}
```

Next, a program that reads the first set of numbers from a single line, and the second set of numbers from the next line:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::getline;
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;

#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;

#include <iterator>
using std::ostream_iterator;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <string>
using std::string;


vector<int>
fetch(ostream& os, istream& is)
{       
    vector<int> result;
    os << "Enter several values, all one one line:\n";
    string line;
    getline(is, line);
    stringstream sline(line);
    int i;
    while(sline >> i)
        result.push_back(i);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1(fetch(cout, cin));
    vector<int> v2(fetch(cout, cin));

    v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
    copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I already have my function that appends the 2 vectors but the problem I'm having is using `cin` to input values into the vectors `a` and `b` and I've already tried your way with 2 separate while loops and it just terminates after entering numbers for the 1st vector

Comment: Also, I'm 2 chapters away from streams

Comment: With my two separate while loops, don't enter EOF (CTRL-Z or CTRL-D) after the first loop. Instead enter "-1". Then enter your second list.

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear the error flags of `std::cin` if you wish to use it again after it fails.

As for appending, why not reserve and insert?

```
void append(std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)
{
    a.reserve(a.size() + b.size());
    a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
}
```

Comment: I'd half expect `insert` to intelligently reserve enough new space for the new data, as it knows from the outset how much it's going to need. Consequently, I'd say that pre-`reserve`ing is a premature optimisation. Not that it hurts.

Comment: @Tomalak you'd be wrong, because there is no way for `vector<>::insert()` to know how many elements it's about to insert without counting them first. And because `insert()` takes a pair of input iterators it is confined to a single pass, and therefore it allocates as it iterates over the input range. This can trigger reallocations.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: well, it could be looking at the category of the iterators and do the optimization if they are random-access (which they are for vector)

Comment: @Itjax but it doesn't have to.

Comment: @Tomalak: I was piqued, so I checked GCC `vector::_M_range_insert`. It does perform this optimization not only for random access, but all forward iterators.

Comment: Well, I could've wrote something similar but the book said `vector<int> append(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)` and your way would change my input for `a`

Comment: @Alex then say `std::vector<int> res(a); res.insert(res.end(), b.begin(), b.end()); return res;`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but I would like to point out an interesting thing about this:

```
while (cin >> input)
{
    if (cin.fail())
    //...
}
```

I don't see any point of `if` inside the `while`. If `cin>>input` fails, the loop will break even before executing `if`.

That means, the `while` block in your code, reduced to this:

```
while (cin >> input)
{
    a.push_back(input);
}
```

This is equivalent to your `while` block!

Comment: @Tomalak: Here is what it looks like in the comment : 
0
down vote
This isn't an answer, but I would like to point out an interesting thing about this:

while (cin >> input)
{
    if (cin.fail())
    //...
}
I don't see any point of if inside the while. If cin>>input fails, the loop will break even before executing if.

That means, the while block in your code, reduced to this:

while (cin >> input)
{
    a.push_back(input);
}
This is equivalent to your while block!

Comment: @Nawaz: I said pretty much the same thing in a question comment, and it looks fine.

Comment: @Tomalak: It doesn't look fine to me. Code should look clear. And in comments it doesn't.

Comment: @Tomalak: If you meant `this kind of formatting`, then its okay when its just one or two words, else it looks very irritating when there're more code.

Comment: @Nawaz: Absolutely, and in my comment it was only a couple of tokens for the same information.

Comment: @Tomalak: Mine is in more detail (and clear). But I know you wouldn't agree. So leave it here :P